# Middleware Setup

Tags: django, middleware

I am trying to setup a message middleware for my marketing app,but the method process_request is not returning anything.
it is running without errors still though not returning message requests.

my middleware.py---

```
from .models import MarketingMessage

class DisplayMarketing():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self, request):
        def process_request(request):
            print("something")
            try:
                request.session['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
            except:
                request.session['marketing_message']  = False
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'marketing.middleware.DisplayMarketing',
]
```

Comment: `process_request()` is not being called anywhere

Comment: @ArakkalAbu sir where too call this method

Comment: response = self.get_response(process_request(request)) use this

Comment: @giveJob   its returning                  AttributeError at /products/
                                     'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use **middleware mixin** process_request will **automatically** called.

try

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisplayMarketing(MiddlewareMixin):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_request(self, request):
            print("something")
            try:
                request.session['marketing_message'] = "bossk"
            except:
                request.session['marketing_message']  = False
```

or, other wise you have call process_request manually

```
from .models import MarketingMessage

class DisplayMarketing():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        def process_request(request):
            print("something")
            try:
                request.session['marketing_message'] ="bossk"
            except:
                request.session['marketing_message']  = False
        response = self.get_response(process_request(request))
        return response
```

Comment: its returning the nonetype has no attribute "is_ajax",  showing error in line 13

Comment: may be other issuse it should not related to middleware, then it is required to show full code

Comment: yeahh it worked for me.thanks for middlewaremaxin method sir.

Comment: Thx, it would help to others if you like the answer

Comment: sorry sir its my fault u r correct.Thanks for helping me sir